# ParserException BIP5004E: An XML parsing error ''DOCTYPE is not allowed by the parser" in occurring in IIB 10.0.0.14 version

Tags: java, xml-parsing, doctype, ibm-integration-bus

One application to get details from an external system was developed and deployed in the IIB `10.0.0.10` version. Later, the application was moved to a new server in which IIB 10.0.0.14 was installed. The issue is that the application gives proper response after deployment or an `EG` restart, but giving parsing error after that. A java compute node is used for connecting to the external system and the parsing error occurs at the below line:

```
String response = getStringValue(detailsObject.getLastChild().getFirstElementByPath("./element1/element2/element3"));
```

The same service is working fine in the old server`(IIB 10.0.0.10)`. Also, the first hit of the service after the deployment will give a proper response to the new server.

Comment: Please can you quote the entire XML parsing error. It would also be useful to know which XML parser you are using. I assume it is XMLNSC, but please confirm.

Comment: Yes, XMLNSC is the parser.The error is as shown below:                                                            An XML parsing error has occurred while parsing the XML document. DOCTYPE is not allowed by the parser.  \/Root\/customerInfo\/XMLNSC.

Comment: I suggest that you capture the input messages and compare them. It looks as if the XMLNSC parser is complaining about the DTD on the input document.

Comment: I compared the request and responses, no difference.The same request works fine in 10.0.0.10 version.In 10.0.0.14 version only, the response is giving a parser error

Comment: I am out of suggestions then. I suggest that you check the README file in the releases between 10.0.0.10 and 10.0.0.14 and if nothing shows up, open a ticket and ask IBM.

Comment: Ya, i have raised a ticket with IBM